# Need to add content to the resolv.conf based on region through cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have to update the content in resolv.conf based upon the region selection through cloudformation template.

Example nameserver 0.0.0.0

the above content need to add in resolv.conf based upon region If I will select US then the nameserver will be different and if it is EU then it will be different

I need how to write this condition in cloudformation template.

Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to put it in the userdata and put a mapping to map the appropriate region to nameserver. Something like

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub 
      - |
        #!/bin/bash 
        nameserver=${nameserver}
        echo "nameserver $nameserver" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
      - nameserver: !FindInMap
          - RegionMap
          - !Ref "AWS::Region"
          - nameserver
```

You will need to declare a RegionMap in mappings to map each region with the appropriate nameserver.

Comment: Thank you for information .${nameserver} this will fetch all my nameservers from route53

Comment: ${nameserver}  this will get all nameservers from route53.Please help me in this

Comment: You will need to hard code all of the name servers per region in a map at the beginning of your template. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html

Comment: Mappings:                                                                                          
  nameserver: {
    us-east-1: [129.0.0.1, 129.0.0.2 129.0.0.3],
    eu-west-1: [129.100.0.1, 129.100.0.2, 139.100.0.3],
  }                                                                                                                                In mapping I have harcoded like this is it correct

Comment: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 341, column 9:
            Fn::Base64: !Sub
            ^
I am getting this error